# How to change screening (halftone pattern) of my printer Cups driver?

Tags: printing, ghostscript, cups

I am using CUPS with the printer driver which use "application/vnd.cups-raster 10 rastertopj" and i am trying to get the look of dither 4x4 print/output but i am clueless where to change the setting for choosing different dithering/halftoning pattern..

i also contacted the cups and they said dithering is done by the driver and also told that If the driver is Ghostscript-based you may be able to change the dither as you’d like, and yes this is indeed Ghostscript-based printer driver/filter cause when i open .PPD file i see *Product:    "(ESP Ghostscript)".

Can you please guide me on how or where to change the dither of the printer filter/driver?

Edited:
this is the halftone output its printing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1prkE.jpg or https://imgur.com/download/7pTksX4

this is the output i am looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHgzx.jpg or https://imgur.com/download/5FnpKEM

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript supports the full range of halftoning defined in the PostScript Language Reference Manual. It also has its own stochastic screening code.

To change the screening, you put the relevant commands in the PostScript file. If you are starting with a PostScript program, then that's where you put the screening. Otherwise you'll have to inject it into the PostScript, which is where you modify the PPD file.

I can't tell you how to do that (because its a CUPS thing, not Ghostscript), nor can I tell you what the PostScript you need is (because I have no idea what the screen you want looks like), you'll have to experiment to match the output you want (note that halftoning is not the same as dithering). Worst case you can use a type 3 halftone dictionary which should produce something similar to what you want, at the cost of needing a lot of data to set it up.

```
<<
/HalftoneType 1
/Frequency 37
/Angle 45
/SpotFunction {180 mul cos
exch 180 mul cos
add 2 div}
>> sethalftone
```

For what its worth, the above is a type 1 halftone dictionary defining a round spot shape and with what I beleive are 'reasonable' values for a 300 dpi monochrome output device.

As to how you get that into the PostScript that Cups sends to Ghostscript, or onto the Ghostscript command line, I can't tell you.

Comment: this is what i am looking for: https://imgur.com/a/KZTQrkp
 is it dot circle pattern?

please sir i have contacted Cups and even the printer support no one is helping out so please KenS i hope you can help me to achieve what i am looking for.. thankyou once again

Comment: Looks like some kind of error diffusion with at least 8 levels of gray. Of course, its quite hard to tell from a scan, especially a scan of a complex image instead of a test strip. However it looks to me like you can't generate that with PostScript, you'll have to render to a contone (or grayscale) image and post-process it.

Comment: its call "Conventional Dot Halftone" (Variable dot size with fixed dot spacing)
please check this image: http://www.thebookdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/stochastic.gif

right now i am getting this output pattern: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNN8p.png

Comment: What you posted is not a simple conventional halftone, or at least it appears not to be, because the pixels are in shades of grey whereas the link you post there is monochrome (black and white). The output you currently get is a strange colour, but appears to me to be an elliptical cell standard halftone, the GIF uses a round cell.

Comment: The original scan you posted appears to be in shades of gray (the cells themselves, that is), so it doesn't look quite like a conventional halftone.Of course that could be an artifact of the scanning process. The pattern in your GIF appears to be a conventional halftone with an elliptical spot shape. If all you want is a standard halftone with a round cell, then you can do that easily enough with a type 1 halftone dictionary. There's an example with a round spot in the PostScript Language reference Manual, see page 486 where the spot function for a round cell is used as an example.

Comment: here is the side by side comparison: https://imgur.com/a/N1rZYSS  
on the left its what i am getting which you call 'elliptical spot shape' and on the right side its what i am getting from Windows 7 PC which i select a generic driver with Halftoning selection: Dither 4x4.
   I just edit the .ppd file and what i paste there?   thank you sir for your reply

Comment: OK I don't know enough about CUPS or your printer to comment much further. It 'looks like' the driver wants a CUPS raster format which it then sends to the device. I have no idea if CUPS will use the PPD of the device with Ghostscript, my guess is not, but I don't know. You don't say what format the input file is in, and its possible the CUPS pipeline might change it (for example into a PDF file). You may not even be using Ghostscript at all..... If you are then you need to change the halftone screen being used by Ghostscript..

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above, you can find out how to create a Type 1 halftone dictionary in PostScript by reading the PostScript Language Reference Manual. You're going to need to research the best settings, so you're going to need to figure out how to do this yourself. Then you need to send that PostScript to Ghostscript, either as part of the program (if CUPS is using the printer PPD file you may be able to edit that, which will get injected into the PostScript), or as a prolog before processing your input file. Since I don't know anything about CUPS queus I can't help you with that.

Comment: Sir, there is also another printer filter openprinting.org provides but it also does the same output print(elliptical cell standard halftone). in the printer filter zip README text mention: The printer data format requires "bitmap" data as is specified by the printer. So, generally, the driver will take "PostScript" as input, use "GhostScript" to convert the data to raw bitmap, and then the driver additionally will format the bitmap. Sir please i really like to fix this issue for me. can i please contact you by email or any other way if possible?

Comment: I won't answer questions by email. The short answer is you need to do some work here, you need to learn firstly how to set a type 1 halftone in PostScript (see the PostScript Language Reference Manual) and then you need to find some way to inject that into your PostScript, either as part of the program, or as part of the Ghostscript command line. I can't tell you how to do either of those because I don't know anything about CUPS.

Comment: Nope, I can help you with the PostScript code (see my edit to my answer) and Ghostscript I cannot help you at all with any Unix devices of any kind.

Comment: this PostScript code where to paste in .ppd file?

thanks sir